# Enable Dark Theme in a Bare React Native Project

Tags: react-native, themes

If you are making the project using expo, there is an option in `app.json` file,  `userInterfaceStyle: "dark"` to enable Dark mode for the project.
How can this be achieved in a bare React Native project?
In the documentation for React Native, they mention the use of `useColorScheme()` hook, But I don't understand how to implement dark theme using the hook in my project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Color scheme is to check for the device's current theme.

```
const Colors = () => {
const isDark = useColorScheme() == 'dark';
return {
   background:isDark ? 'black':'white',
   text:isDark ? 'white':'black'
  }
}
export default Colors;
```

example

```
import Colors from './Colors';

const Home = ()=>{
 const colors = Colors();
return (
   <View style={{flex:1,backgroundColor:colors.background}}>
      <Text style={{color:colors.text}}>hello world</Text>
   </View>
)
}
```

Comment: but if you want to change the theme on button press i think you need a global state like redux